# Powershell concatenate an Environment variable with path

Tags: string, environment-variables, filepath, powershell-4.0

So I have this code:

```
$userprofile=Get-ChildItem Env:USERPROFILE
$localpath="$userprofile\some\path"
```

I would expect output of the below from `$localpath`:

```
c:\users\username\some\path
```

However what I get is:

```
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry\some\path
```

So, of course, something like `cd $localpath` fails. How would I accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A convenient way to obtain the string value rather than the dictionary entry (which is technically what `Get-ChildItem` is accessing) is to just use the variable syntax: `$Env:USERPROFILE` rather than `Get-ChildItem Env:USERPROFILE`.

```
$localpath = "$env:USERPROFILE\some\path"
```

For more information:

[PowerShell Environment Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/providers/Environment-Provider)

[about_Environment_Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Environment_Variables)

Also, the [`Join-Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet is a good way to combine two parts of a path.

```
$localpath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'some\path'
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the thoughtful edit providing examples.

Comment: If you come from the CMD-heavy world of Windows Scripting, don't forget to include `$` in you setter name. In CMD, `Set varname=something` would have to be, `$varname=something`, _**not**_ `varname=something`.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party and apart from whether the example is a good way of getting an environment variable, the actual answer to the question is this:

```
$userprofile = Get-ChildItem Env:USERPROFILE
$localpath="$($userprofile.Value)\some\path"
```

This might be functionality of newer versions of Powershell since the original question though.